Error Code: site_verification_failed.connection_error in iThemes / Solid Security Basic
After setup of "Solid Security Basic (Itheme)" giving an error at the time of auto scan. Find the below exact error and provide the solution.
Site Scan
An error occurred while running the scheduled site scan on ....:
Error Message: Unable to determine if the scan target is allowed: Target site returned invalid response. Is your site in a coming soon or privacy mode where users have to enter a password to visit? iThemes Security won't be able to scan your site in this mode. Try scanning again after your site is ready for launch!
Error Code: site_verification_failed.connection_error
